# auto confirm authenticated user to Drupal Newsletter Module

Tags: 7, emails

I tried to make auto confirm authenticated user to Drupal Newsletter Module but i failed. in other words... is it possible that users do not receive a verification email and immediately confirmed?

I un-tick this option:

**Send confirmation email**
*Attention: If you disable confirmation e-mails, users will be able to subscribe others without their permission.*

But still find that all the subscribers in my list are unconfirmed.

Please help..

Comment: What module are you using? Can you link it?

Comment: Newsletter Module: https://www.drupal.org/project/newsletter